# Reversing a singly linked list?

Tags: java, reverse, singly-linked-list

This is the code I was given for the Singly Linked List, however I am struggling on completing the Reverse function. This was the code and my attempt at the reverse function. I keep getting 2 errors that say "Undeclared variable: node" and "imcompatible types: Node cannot be converted to Linkedlist".

```
class LinkedList
{
    Node head;
    Node current;
    Node previous;

    public Object Get()
    {
        return current != null ? current.GetData() : null;
    }

    public void Next()
    {
        if (current != null)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public void Head()
    {
        previous = null;
        current = head;
    }

    public void Insert(Object data)
    {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        node.next = current;

        if (current == head)
            head = node;
        else
            previous.next = node;

        current = node;
    }

    public void Remove()
    {
        if (current == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid position to remove");

        if (current == head)
            head = current.next;
        else
            previous.next = current.next;

        current = current.next;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        for (Head(); Get() != null; Next())
            System.out.println(Get());
    }

    public LinkedList Reverse()
    {
        Node previous = null;  
        Node current = node;  
        Node forward;  

        while (current != null) 
        {  
            forward = current.next;  
            current.next = previous;  
            previous = current;  
            current = forward;  
        }  
    return previous;  
    }
```

}

There is also class Node:
class Node
{
// Public reference to next node
public Node next;

```
    // Private data field
    Object data;

    Node(Object data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Object GetData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And this is the main function:
class Test
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
// creating a singly linked list
LinkedList linked_list = new LinkedList();

```
        // adding node into singly linked list 
        linked_list.Insert(Integer.valueOf(10));
        linked_list.Next();
        linked_list.Insert(Integer.valueOf(11));
        linked_list.Next();
        linked_list.Insert(Integer.valueOf(12));
        
        // printing a singly linked 
        linked_list.Print();
        
        // reversing the singly linked list 
        linked_list.Reverse(); 
        
        // printing the singly linked list again 
        linked_list.Print(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post here your driver program as well from which these functions are getting called? That can help to understand the problem better.

Comment: I can definitely see one problem, in your reverse function, Node current = node;
Where is node defined ?

Comment: Sure, thank you! There is also class Node.                                                                   class Node
{
 // Public reference to next node
 public Node next;

 // Private data field
 Object data;

 Node(Object data)
 {
  this.data = data;
 }

 public Object GetData()
 {
  return data;
 }
}

Comment: No i mean can you post the main function of this class.. From where you are calling the functions of LinkedList class.

Comment: I assume that you wanted `Node current = head` and change the return type to `Node`.

Comment: The second problem is that Reverse needs to return a `LinkedList` value, but it is returning a `Node` value.  That's why you are getting the "incompatible types" error.

Comment: Actually ... the more I look at this, the more broken it looks.  Why does `LinkedList` have a `next` and `previous`?  Those are fields of the `Node` class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution:

```
public class ListReverser {
    public static Node<Integer> reverse(Node head) {
        Node current = head;
        while(current.getNext() != null) {
            Node next =  current.getNext();
            current.setNext(next.getNext());
            next.setNext(head);
            head = next;
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```